# Is it possible for a bard to use an instrument to cast spells while holding a weapon in each hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, bard, spellcasting

I am playing a bard in 5e. Is it possible to use an instrument to cast spells while holding a weapon in each hand? (If I am correct that you need the instrument to cast bardic spells.)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Dual wielding requires both your action and your bonus action, so it would be difficult if not impossible to cast a spell in the same turn even if you could use an instrument while holding two weapons.

Comment: It would be so that I don't have to switch back and forth and lose actions when I have to sheath to cast a spell.

Comment: I've done an edit to try to make it clearer what your question is really about.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a complicated issue. To start with, you don't *need* to use an instrument to cast spells - necessarily.

> You can use a musical instrument (found in chapter 5) as a spellcasting focus for your bard spells.

So, what does it mean to use a spellcasting focus?

> A character
>   can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus
>   (found in chapter 5) in place of the components specified
>   for a spell.

So you can use an instrument instead of the actual material components when casting any spell that requires material components. However:

> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access these
>   components—or to hold a spellcasting focus—but it can
>   be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic
>   components.

So no, you can't use an instrument to cast spells while holding two weapons - you have to have a hand free. The really important point here, though, is that not every spell has material components. Similarly:

> If a spell
>   requires a somatic component, the caster must have free
>   use of at least one hand to perform these gestures.

So if a spell requires a material component or a somatic component (or both), then you're out of luck, you'll need a free hand. On the other hand, if a spell only has verbal components (which is the case for many spells on the Bard spell list) then you can cast it while holding a weapon in each hand.

Finally, it's definitely worth taking a look at the War Caster feat, which among other things, grants you this benefit:

> You can perform the somatic components of spells even when you have weapons or a shield in one or both hands.

This would allow you to cast spells with somatic components while holding your weapons, although you'd still be out of luck for spells with material components.

Answer (score 2):

If your DM allows you to use subclasses from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (an official D&D book released in 2018), there is a [College of Swords](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#CollegeofSwords) bard subclass (on p. 15), which allows you to use a melee weapon you are proficient with as a spellcasting focus for bard spells.

In this case, you could cast any bard spell with a material (M) component that doesn't have a cost with a melee weapon in each hand just like you want, as page 203 of the *Player's Handbook* states in the rules for [material components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#MaterialM):

> Casting some spells requires particular objects, specified in parentheses in the component entry. A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in chapter 5) in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.
>
> If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each casting of the spell. A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell's material components — or to hold a spellcasting focus  but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.

If a spell has a Somatic (S) component but not a Material (M) component, or it has a Material (M) component that has a cost/is consumed, you will need to use your free object interaction (you get one per turn for free) to put away one of your weapons for the turn and have a free hand to cast the spell.

Since you are casting with your action or bonus action that turn and not attacking, you won't be able to use Two-Weapon Fighting anyway so no loss there, and you still have one of your weapons out to make opportunity attacks with. Then, next turn, you have the option to draw the weapon again with your free object interaction and be able to use Two-Weapon Fighting, or keep the hand free and cast another spell.

If this is still not good enough for you, you can get the [War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/war-caster) feat (PHB, p. 170); then you will only have to put away your weapon for spells with a Material (M) component that has a cost or is consumed (which are rare). This is because one of the benefits of War Caster is:

> You can perform the somatic components of spells even when you have weapons or a shield in one or both hands.

You may want War Caster anyway for its other benefits.

A spell with neither a Somatic (S) nor a Material (M) component can be cast regardless of what is in your hands.

Note that the College of Swords subclass is taken instead of one of the subclasses in the *Player's Handbook* (such as the College of Valor).